# URLs matching regexp very slow on some strings

Tags: python, regex, url, performance

Here is my regexp for finding URLs in some string (i need the group for the domain because further actions are based on the domain) and i noticed for some strings 'fffffffff' in this example it's very slow, there is something obvious i missing?

```
>>> URL_ALLOWED = r"[a-z0-9$-_.+!*'(),%]"
>>> URL_RE = re.compile(
...     r'(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?'  # protocol
...     r'(?:www.)?' # www
...     r'('  # host - start
...         r'(?:'
...             r'[a-z0-9]'  # first character of domain('-' not allowed)
...             r'(?:'
...                 r'[a-z0-0-]*'  #  characters in the middle of domain
...                 r'[a-z0-9]' #  last character of domain('-' not allowed)
...             r')*'
...             r'\.'  # dot before next part of domain name
...         r')+'
...         r'[a-z]{2,10}'  # TLD
...         r'|'  # OR
...         r'(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}'  # IP address
...     r')' # host - end
...     r'(?::[0-9]+)?'  # port
...     r'(?:\/%(allowed_chars)s+/?)*'  # path
...     r'(?:\?(?:%(allowed_chars)s+=%(allowed_chars)s+&)*'  # GET params
...     r'%(allowed_chars)s+=%(allowed_chars)s+)?'  # last GET param
...     r'(?:#[^\s]*)?' % {  # anchor
...         'allowed_chars': URL_ALLOWED
...     },
...     re.IGNORECASE
... )
>>> from time import time
>>> strings = [
...     'foo bar baz',
...     'blah blah blah blah blah blah',
...     'f' * 10,
...     'f' * 20,
...     'f' * 30,
...     'f' * 40,
... ]
>>> def t():
...     for string in strings:
...             t1 = time()
...             URL_RE.findall(string)
...             print string, time() - t1
... 
>>> t()
foo bar baz 3.91006469727e-05
blah blah blah blah blah blah 6.98566436768e-05
ffffffffff 0.000313997268677
ffffffffffffffffffff 0.183916091919
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff 178.445468903
```

Yeah i know there is another solution to use very simple regexp (word that contain dots for example) and use urlparse later to get domain, but urlparse doesn't work as expected when we don't have protocol in URL:

```
>>> urlparse('example.com')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='example.com', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('http://example.com')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='example.com', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('example.com/test/test')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='example.com/test/test', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('http://example.com/test/test')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='example.com', path='/test/test', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('example.com:1234/test/test')
ParseResult(scheme='example.com', netloc='', path='1234/test/test', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('http://example.com:1234/test/test')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='example.com:1234', path='/test/test', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

Yeah prepending http:// is also a solution(i'm still not 100% sure if there are no other urlparse issues) but i'm curious what's wrong with this regexp anyway

Comment: That regex makes my brain hurt

Comment: My gut feeling is that any search target with lots of h's or f's (or longer substrings) that match the start of the pattern in it will chug.  Have you considered trying to preprocess the string by tokenizing delimted by whitepace, then running a simpler regex against those tokens?  Trying to oneline things isn't always the fastest way.

Comment: urlparse there is working as expected. It's just that what you're passing it isn't a URL. "example.com" isn't a URL, and "myshellserver:22" isn't a URL either. You have to be prepared to accept that this approach will produce false positives sometimes, and if so, maybe the simple word-with-a-dot regex would be fine. Otherwise I agree with IamChuckB

Comment: The regex doesn't make my head hurt but please, Please _PLEASE_ use python's `r"""..."""` multiline string syntax when formulating long regexes! All those _quotes_ make my head hurt. (p.s. Your regex would be fine with a couple fixes...) See my article on URI regexes: [Regular Expression URI Validation](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html) I'm working on an answer to this question as we speak...

Comment: There are too many typos in this post so I've given up on my answer. But for starters you want to fix your URL_ALLOWED which has an unescaped dash which is including the range from `'$'` through `'_'`. The speed problem is due to a catastrophic backtracking-like structure (i.e. `(a*)*`) within your sub-domain expression. You've also got an unescaped dot after the www.

Comment: @ridgerunner have no idea how come i didn't notice that typos, thanks a lot

Comment: @moopet yeah i know, I just hoped it would parse them, but adding http:// making them valid anyway:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it happens becuase of this part

```py
...         r'(?:'
...             r'[a-z0-9]'  # first character of domain('-' not allowed)
...             r'(?:'
...                 r'[a-z0-0-]*'  #  characters in the middle of domain
...                 r'[a-z0-9]' #  last character of domain('-' not allowed)
...             r')*'
...             r'\.'  # dot before next part of domain name
...         r')+'
```

You should not use construction like this ([set_of_symbols#1]*[set_of_symbols#2])* if set_of_symbols#1 and set_of_symbols#2 have same symbols.

Please try to use the following code:

```py
...         r'(?:'
...             r'[a-z0-9]'  # first character of domain('-' not allowed)
...             r'[a-z0-0-]*'  #  characters in the middle of domain
...             r'(?<=[a-z0-9])' #  last character of domain('-' not allowed)
...             r'\.'  # dot before next part of domain name
...         r')+'
```

It should work better.

Comment: Thanks, when changed this lines and fixed typos @ridgerunner found it works damn fast:)

Answer (score 0):

fyi, you can also use the re.VERBOSE flag to make this more readable

```
 URL_RE = re.compile(r"""
    (?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?                            # protocol
    (?:www.)?                                           # www
    (                                                   # host - start
        (?:
            [a-z0-9]                                    # first character of domain('-' not allowed)
            (?:
                [a-z0-0-]*                              #  characters in the middle of domain
                [a-z0-9]                                #  last character of domain('-' not allowed)
            )*
            \.                                          # dot before next part of domain name
        )+
        [a-z]{2,10}                                     # TLD
        |                                               # OR
        (?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}                   # IP address
    )                                                   # host - end
    (?::[0-9]+)?                                        # port
    (?:\/%(allowed_chars)s+/?)*                         # path
    (?:\?(?:%(allowed_chars)s+=%(allowed_chars)s+&)*    # GET params
    %(allowed_chars)s+=%(allowed_chars)s+)?             # last GET param
    (?:#[^\s]*)?
""" % {  # anchor
         'allowed_chars': URL_ALLOWED
     },
     re.IGNORECASE|re.VERBOSE
 )
```